How can we clearly say what is or is not a question?
I think we can all agree that just adding a question mark to the end of this (and the post it refers to) does not make it a question: 
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/40424/shameless-moderators-deleted-my-question-truth-cannot-be-hidden-forever-you-ha?noredirect=1#comment46465_40424
The tour does not have much in there explicit enough about what is or is not a question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/tour
It seems like it should be basic enough that no one needs to point it out, but...
What clear definition for what is or is not a question (even before deciding whether it's a good question) applies on the bitcoin.stackexchange.com Q&A site? 

Could you please refrain from starting each post with "// , "? I fail to see any benefit and find its visual clutter to be disruptive to my reading.

Good questions: 

Specify a clear topic that allows other participants to gauge what would constitute an encompassing answer. 
Show that the asker has spent some minimal effort to try to find an answer himself. 
If controversial statements are made, they are presented in form of arguments with supportive evidence.
Are useful to more than one isolated individual.
Are asked openly to allow for a range of answers. Especially, loaded questions or statements asking for support do not fulfill this.

You can find more information in our help center in the category Asking. Or have a look at the distilled version at How to Ask.
You might also find this article by one of Stackoverflow's founders on the dynamics between questions and answers interesting: Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand.


I think we can all agree that just adding a question mark to the end of this (and the post it refers to) does not make it a question:

It's also possible to have a question that has no question marks:

Asked by $someone   
I'm having problems with this code:
code

When I run it on linux, it produces this error. It works on windows,
  and I've tried this and this. I've tried googling this, and I tried this, but that didn't help either.

This never explicitly asks a question, but it has a clear problem, a explanation of what they've tried, and talks about what references they've consulted.
There isn't a hard and fast rule; it's an "I know it when I see it," kind of thing. If we made an explicit rule, there would be so many exceptions and so many loopholes that it would be a huge pain to comply with.
Warning signs:

(on main site) Uses question to complain about how previous questions have been removed.
Asks something vague, then answers own question with a blog post that's linked.
The asker expects a particular answer.

